# When is it a good idea to use the CSS display property?

Tags: css

I think I first learned of this property when I thought "I should put this list of items in a ul, but I want it to be laid out horizontally. I wonder if I can do that with CSS?" When I googled this, I found a couple of sites suggesting that I create a CSS rule that would change the value of the display property of the li elements to inline. I've also seen the suggestion that a div (or other block element) be given `display: table-cell` in order to force the vertical align property to work. These techniques seem kind of hacky. Does that make sense?

This might not be a good analogy, but it seems like trying to ride a car as if it were a motorcycle. Yeah, I could replace the steering wheel with handle bars, wear a helmet, and remove all the passenger seating, but how the heck is a car going to drive on two wheels??

Comment: Coincidentally, I ran into a situation where I thought changing display to block would help me with something at work today. The problem was I was trying to embed a YouTube video, and I guess the object element takes display: inline by default. This gives it a little space on the bottom, in case it contains a letter such as 'g', which hangs bellow the baseline. Changing to display: block helped in ff, but not ie. Now, I have to find another way to get rid of that space. +0.5 for hack; +0.5 for ie sucks.

Answer (score 3):

Basically the principle is:

- Markup is semantic;
- CSS is for display.

The lines in practice blur somewhat but it's a good starting point.

So a list is a way of creating a flat or hierarchical group of items. You can use `display` to change that from a vertical list to a horizontal list (`display: inline` or using `float`), etc.

So you use the `display` property where it's appropriate to how you want your markup to appear. Sound vague? It is but I guess so is the question.

Answer (score 1):

A list is a list is a list as they said it.  It's a list of thing.  How you display it, well, it's up to how you want to visualize it, right?

It's all about separation of concern.  One is **what** the thing is (LI, UL, OL), the other one is **how you display** it (CSS).  It does not have to be tied up tightly together.